# Shooting a bullet out of a point in a rotating circle using C# within Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a circle object that can be rotated and moved around on a 2D plane. There is a point on the circle where the object must be fired from. I'm currently using this script.

```
 var newBullet = GameObject.Instantiate(bulletPrefab) as Bullet;
    newBullet.transform.position = transform.position;
```

and then in the bullet script I'm using

```
void Fire()
{
    rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector3.right * 100);

}
```

At the moment the bullet is only shooting and travelling in the right direction. What can I use to make the bullet fire out of the circle with the applied rotation?

```
  public void ApplyRotation(float turnInput)
{
    //TODO: Complete this code

  if (turnInput == -1)
  {
      transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * 180);
  }
  if (turnInput == 1)
  {
      transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * -180);
  }
}
```

This is how I rotate the circle player.

Comment: `AddForce(bulletPosition - circleCenter)`?

Comment: Clearly the first peice of code is in Javascript.

Comment: you can use `var` and `as` in C# as well

Answer (score 0):

You can store rotation of your circle in a value and when you instantiate a bullet sent that value to it with a function and use that angle to force bullet like a code below:

```
Vector3 dir = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward) * Vector3.right;
rigidbody2D.AddForce(dir*force);
```

in this example the angle starts on the right and goes counter-clockwise.